# how to get checked value from a list of dynamically selected created checkboes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

I have my checkboxes dynamically populated here(using thymeleaf).
I have of list of checkboxes with values assigned dynamically, when my page gets loaded.

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li th:each="model : ${model}">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cbCheck" th:field="*{model}" th:value="${model}" />
    <label th:text="${model}"></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need the value of the checked check boxes, when user presses 'submit' button . Any Solutions ?

I tried giving them a common name . and accessing value like this :

```
var list = $("input[name='inputCheck']:checked").map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();

alert(list);


}
```

But alert is always empty . 
Would like some solutions for this ?

Entire Code used :

```
<body>
<h2> LIST OF RULES ACTIVE</h2>
<div id="RuleList">
    <ul class="list">
       <li th:each="model : ${model}">
         <input type="checkbox" name="inputCheck" th:id="${model}" th:field="*{model}" th:value="${model}" />
         <label th:text="${model}"></label>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <button type="button" onclick="sendResponse()" id="DeActivate">DeActivate</button>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<script>

function sendResponse()
{
/*var array = [];
if(document.getElementsByName("inputCheck").checked)
    {
    array.push(document.getElementsByName("inputCheck").value);
    alert(array);
    }

}*/



var list = $("input[name='inputCheck']:checked").map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();

alert(list);


}

</script>

</body>
```

The program flow is not entering the checkbox checked condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get value in javascript/jquery from a list of dynamically created checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61462429/how-to-get-value-in-javascript-jquery-from-a-list-of-dynamically-created-checkbo)

Comment: No it doesnt work. I tried accessing the values by giving  common checkbox name for every checkbox. It didnt work.

Comment: I have added a demo using the common name `inputCheck` and the alert is working fine. Please update the demo to show that alert is not working.

Comment: @palaѕн here is the code I m using .. I have paste the entire page code above.

Comment: Sorry, but not able to reproduce this issue, as I don't know what is `th:each` and other markup here is.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('.cbCheck');
for (i=0; i<list .length; i++){
    alert(check[i].value)
}
```